# How to fit a surface to points in 3D and determine its center?

Tags: 3d, surfaces, interpolation

I have 8 points in space which form one finite element's face made of 4 corner nodes and 4 midnodes, and to which I would like to fit a surface and then, determine the coordinates of its center.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/28K7a.png

The nodes are not in the same plane.

Let's assume that the coordinates of my 8 points are stored in 3 vectors called x, y, and z.

I am using octave (= matlab syntax) to try and solve this problem but I struggle with the maths.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How is center of any arbitrary  surface defined?

Comment: I don't know if there's a possibility to determine its barycentre (centroid) somehow.

Comment: Essential question : do the projections on the x0y of your points $f(x_k,y_k)$ are more or less along a $3 \times 3$ square grid ? In this case, it suffices to adapt a surface $z=f(x,y).$

Comment: @JeanMarie Not necessarily. I would prefer to keep working on a general case where all 3 dimensions can vary.

Comment: IMHO the best would be first to find the best (in the sense of least squares) plane approximation of your "cloud" of 8 points, and then do the patch method of @Nominal Animal with this plane considered as a new XY plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just one patch in a parametrized surface, we'd need to know (some of) the points in the neighbouring patches to make it continuous.

If we assume this is a solitary patch -- that is, we ignore continuity at the edge of the patch --, we can quite easily fit a polynomial to it. First, let's renumber the known points in the patch first:
$$\begin{array}{r|rrr}
v=1 & p_{02} & p_{12} & p_{22} \\
\;  & p_{01} & \;     & p_{21} \\
\;  & p_{00} & p_{10} & p_{20} \\
\hline
0   & \;     & \;     & u=1
\end{array}$$

Let's construct an interpolating polynomial with eight coefficients. We cannot use
$$f(u,v) = \sum_{i,j=0}^{2} C_{ij} u^i v^j$$
because that has *nine* coefficients. We also want to make it symmetric with respect to $u$ and $v$ (no directional bias, that is), so let's use interpolating quartic polynomial
$$\begin{array}{rccl}
f(u,v) \; = & (1-u)   & (1-v)   & C_{00} \\
          + &    u    & (1-v)   & C_{20} \\
          + & (1-u)   &   v     & C_{02} \\
          + &    u    &   v     & C_{22} \\
          + & (1-u) u & (1-v)   & C_{10} \\
          + & (1-u) u &    v    & C_{12} \\
          + & (1-u)   & (1-v) v & C_{01} \\
          + &    u    & (1-v) v & C_{21}
\end{array}$$
This construction allows us to drop one coefficient ($C_{11}$, which would correspond to term $(1-u) u (1-v) v C_{11}$ above).

(I formed the above in the order shown; the idea is to make it obvious we want to be symmetric with respect to $u$, $1-u$ and $v$, $1-v$, without assuming any coefficient is zero -- like we would if we were to just use the sum and assume $C_{11}=0$. I wanted to *restrict* the behaviour of the interpolating polynomial, not force one of its coefficients to zero. This seemed like the simplest way. Edited to add: I now noticed that there is no coefficient corresponding to $u^2 v^2$, so I could have used the sum instead with $C_{22}=0$. Ho hum; me not being a mathematician really shows, eh? )

Now, if we use *f(u,v)* to interpolate the point coordinates, we find that the coefficients are
$$\begin{cases}
C_{00} = x_{00} \\
C_{01} = 4 x_{01} - 2 ( x_{00} + x_{02} ) \\
C_{02} = x_{02} \\
C_{10} = 4 x_{10} - 2 ( x_{00} + x_{20} ) \\
C_{12} = 4 x_{12} - 2 ( x_{22} + x_{02} ) \\
C_{20} = x_{20} \\
C_{21} = 4 x_{21} - 2 ( x_{22} + x_{20} ) \\
C_{22} = x_{22}
\end{cases}$$
and same for $y$ and $z$ coordinates.

Substituting the above to $f(1/2,1/2)$ we get the coordinates for the middle point $(x_{11}, y_{11}, z_{11})$,
$$\begin{cases}
x_{11} = \frac{x_{10} + x_{01} + x_{12} + x_{21}}{2} - \frac{x_{00} + x_{02} + x_{20} + x_{22}}{4} \\
y_{11} = \frac{y_{10} + y_{01} + y_{12} + y_{21}}{2} - \frac{y_{00} + y_{02} + y_{20} + y_{22}}{4} \\
z_{11} = \frac{z_{10} + z_{01} + z_{12} + z_{21}}{2} - \frac{z_{00} + z_{02} + z_{20} + z_{22}}{4}
\end{cases}$$

Indeed, if we consider the symmetry requirements, it should be clear that all interpolating polynomials (that only use the data given here, and not from e.g. neighbouring patches), the midpoint coordinates are, and have to be,
$$\begin{cases}
x_{11} = A ( x_{00} + x_{02} + x_{20} + x_{22}) + B (x_{10} + x_{01} + x_{12} + x_{21} ) \\
y_{11} = A ( y_{00} + y_{02} + y_{20} + y_{22}) + B (y_{10} + y_{01} + y_{12} + y_{21} ) \\
z_{11} = A ( z_{00} + z_{02} + z_{20} + z_{22}) + B (z_{10} + z_{01} + z_{12} + z_{21} ) \\
\end{cases}$$
with $A$ and $B$ depending only on the interpolation polynomial used; otherwise, the direction selected for $u$ and $v$ affects the interpolation!

Comment: Hello and thank you so much already!I just tested it on a small example and this seems to work perfectly. I will conduct another bunch of tests and will come back here to post a definite feedback and validate your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @Lois: For what it's worth, I get the same interpolating polynomial if I start with $f(u,v)=\sum_{i,j=0}^2 C_{ij} u^i v^j$ with $C_{22}=0$, and therefore the same midpoint, too. So, I do believe this method gives you the simplest interpolating polynomial.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for taking the time and detailing this solution. It's exactly what I needed to solve my problem and it works just perfectly, as I only need to consider the patches one at a time.Could you please send me a link to some literature on how to create the polynomial and interpolate the coordinates? So I can understand it deeper. My maths knowledge is really foggy :)

Comment: @Lois: I'm not a mathematician; I'm a computational physicist, who uses math only as a tool to solve problems. I'm afraid I don't have any good literature references, as I've basically learned the above from solving problems involving sampled data ... In truth, I've found Wikipedia articles ([polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation), [bicubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation), [Bézier surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_surface), and [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation)) ...

Comment: @Lois: ... more useful than any book or article I've read -- except perhaps those related to computer graphics (where both speed and avoiding (visual) artefacts is valued). If you do have a programming background, the [Numerical Recipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_Recipes) (one using a language you are comfortable with) is definitely a good one to delve into, and also covers interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Coons patch in the following way:

1. Create a quadratic polynomial curve interpolating 3 points for each edge,
2. Use Coons patch to blend the 4 edges to create your surface. See this ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coons_patch)) for details about Coons patch.
3. Evaluate your "center" point at (s,t)=(0.5,0.5)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll read further about Coons patch, which I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Any number of surfaces can be fitted through 4 corner points  and 4 mid corner points to define a surface with second order continuity across the edges.

Its scalar invariants like $H,K$ (Mean & Gauss curvatures) need to be specified to complete its spatial definition, but even then it is tough, not well developed so far afik.

A quick/dirty way for each of the three $(x,y,z) $ coordinates is :-

$$(c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4+2 m_1+2 m_2+2 m_3+2 m_4)/12$$

where $c$ is for corner point and $m$ mid-point.

EDIT1

A quartic polynomial with eight coefficients could also be attempted numerically.

$$ a1\, x^4+ a2\, y^4 + z^4 + a3 \,x^2y^2 + a4\, y^2z^2 + a5\, z^2 x^2 + a6 \,xy + a7\, yz + a8 \,zx =1 $$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution!! I think this would work well too. But I chose NominalAnimal's answer as the correct one, as it really break down the method in details.